# Replacing Microsoft Access with a different portable database and interface

Tags: database, sqlite, ms-access

Our company is upgrading all work computers soon and no longer supporting MS Access. Unfortunately, a lot of important database is stored in a plethora of Access databases with many differing styles of interfaces. Storing it all on a database server is out of the question. What is a good portable (non-server) database system that I can use?

The one I'm leaning toward is SQLite, but I'd also like to be able to write interfaces to query the data. If I use SQLite, what is a good way to write a query interface that will work on a lot of Windows machines natively?

EDIT: Data migration will not be a problem. I'm more worried about interface migration. What is a good way to write a query interface for one of these portable database systems?

EDIT2: It seems that there's some confusion as to what I mean by "query interface". I don't need a complete query system. I'm simply looking to create a simple frontend through which I can search the Database by table and by fields.

Comment: You not 100% clear what you mean by UI. Are you looking for JUST some kind of query builder as your UI (do you users really spend all day in the query builder). Or do you have a UI in terms of forms, reports and code here? I am just suggesting that using the term "query interface" in place of forms + reports + code that creates a typical UI in Access is confusing this issue. This could well mean that NONE of suggestions here solves this issue of what you use for reports and forms. So, is this just query system you need or do you have things like forms + reports here?

Comment: Well, the current Access DBs have some interfaces using forms, reports, and VBA code. They are pretty much just a glorified search engine for these databases. I don't think the users would have the know-how to be able to use a complete query builder system. 

I'd like to just have a simple interface to search the DB by various fields and display/output the results. This was trivial with Access VBA, but seems a bit more complicated with .NET or others.I'm now thinking an HTML/PHP solution would be good because it would be easy to scale it if we ever decide to move it to a server.

Comment: Your bosses are complete idiots. They are taking away from you the only tool available for doing the job their employees need to perform.

Comment: @Dirk Ferguson  - Given your second edit, is this tool purely for use by a developer or are we talking about a user interface that would be used by non-developers?

Comment: @Dirk Ferguson - If we are talking about a tool to be used by non-developers, then you are talking about a tool to build a user interface and that is an entirely different question from the question you have given us. The choices are numerous (PHP, ASP, ASP.NET, Java, Windows Forms, WPF...).

Comment: Sorry, but when someone asks as question about replacing Access, by default one should assume that they mean replacing ALL of Access, not just the database engine, which is by far the lesser part of the equation when someone says "replace Access." Given the context of the question, this should have been clear to anybody reading it (unless, of course, they are clueless as to what Access actually is, i.e., a database application development tool with a default databases engine, Jet/ACE).

Comment: @David-W-Fenton - So clear in fact that you chose to avoid submitting an answer when you "knew" that everyone else was on the wrong track. Hindsight is 20/20.

Comment: @Dirk: It's not at all clear why your company has chosen to quit supporting Access as a *frontend.*  Access makes a perfectly good frontend environment; it is the *backend* that can be unstable if you're trying to use it in a multi-user environment and your people are not experts with Access concurrency.  As with all development environments, you can write perfectly wretched programs in Access if you don't know what you are doing.  That's not Access' fault.

Comment: @Thomas: Why should someone submit an answer that duplicates a detailed correct answer that has already been posted, i.e., the one from @HK1?

Answer (score 8):

Judging by the title of your question, you are concerned about what database (i.e. data container) should be used in place of Microsoft Access. However, viewing your question and the ensuing answers and comments, your greater concern is actually what to use to design the Application/user interface, what you are referring to as the "query interface".

Here's a couple things you need to realize:

1) SELECT queries allow you to extract data from a database. However, the data has to get into the database somehow. At no point have you specified whether or not your so-called "query interface" is also used for data entry. If it is in fact used for data entry, as I suspect it is, then you should concern yourself with how your going to design your "application", not your "query interface". Data entry often requires a certain amount of guidance and logic that is defined outside of the database. This logic includes (but is not limited to) things like validation rules, input masks, parent child relationships that are enforced by the GUI design. This is essentially an application, not merely a "query interface". Applications are usually designed to make data entry easier than having the user enter data directly into the tables. But even here you must realize that ultimately a user can't even enter data directly into a table without some type of application GUI, whether that GUI is something you've designed or not.

2) Microsoft Access is a Rapid Application Development (RAD) tool that allows you to quickly and easily design and save queries, forms, and reports. It appears to me that you're real question is, **What RAD tool other than Microsoft Access can I use to develop queries and forms for viewing and entering data in small desktop databases? And what database would you recommend we use together with the RAD tool you're recommending?**

Assuming I've properly defined your actual question, allow me to give my own viewpoint on this question. First, as has already been pointed out in another answer, as long as the clients are running MS Windows, you don't really need to move away from using Access/Jet/ACC as your database (data container, the part that holds the tables). As long as MDAC is installed an Access database should be "machine readable".

It seems to me the more important question here is what RAD tool should you use in place of Microsoft Access? After you answer this question perhaps it will help you answer the first question, of what database should be used. In answer to this question, let's be honest. While Microsoft Access has it's shortcomings, you probably won't find any other RAD tool that allows you to so easily create Forms for data entry. FileMaker Pro is one of the only competing products that I know of.

Yes, you could use Visual Studio .Net to create .exe runtimes. These runtimes can include forms for viewing and entering data as well as reports. I think you'll find that the learning curve is pretty major, especially if you are not yet familiar with ADO.Net which is very different from DAO or ADO Classic. If you want to give your users ways to create their own queries/filters or reports you'll have to design this functionality into your GUI since Visual Studio doesn't give you the easy wizards and design tools you'll find in Microsoft Access. While Visual Studio is far more powerful than MS Access, you need to realize that the development time for even the simplest of applications is probably going to be much higher, especially when you are first learning.

Are there any other RAD tools you could possibly use? I know little if anything about the different design tools listed here but this might be a good place for you to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rapid_application_development_tools#Desktop_Rapid_Application_Development_Tools

Comment: Wow, great response! Yes, you are correct in that I'm more concerned about the interface than the database system. The interface will be mainly used for queries (hence why I called it a "query interface", but I guess that was a little vague), however, it would be beneficial to maybe add the ability to modify or add entries to the tables, but that isn't necessary. I'm assuming the end user of these interfaces know nothing about SQL and simply want to search the database and be able to see the results (and maybe export to another format)

Comment: Also, I'm familiar with .NET programming, however, I've never had to use ADO.NET, so it wouldn't be a problem. However, those RAD tools look like an interesting idea. They would save me a lot of time. Thanks for all the helpful information.

Comment: MDAC has almost nothing to do with Jet data accessibility. Jet is part of the OS and DAO is installed by default, so the MDAC is pretty much irrelevant unless you want to use OLEDB to access the Jet data.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, depending on what you are doing with these databases, would be Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition which does not require an installer.

No matter what database you choose, you are going to be faced with migrating your queries to a different dialect of the SQL language (the actual syntax of your queries). They all have their quirks and features (and missing features). That is just the nature of the beast. It should be noted that you can still access a MS Access database in code without requiring the installation of MS Access.

---

It appears that the nature of the question has changed dramatically since it was originally posted. The question has apparently morphed into one about finding an user interface development environment that has similar features to Access. This is obviously an entirely different question than finding a replacement for Access (or specifically Jet for those anal retentives in the audience) as a database engine.

There are many alternatives and it depends greatly on whether you wish to continue with a Windows application or whether you wish to move to a browser based interface. Given various comments, it sounds like you may still want a Windows based solution. A couple of solutions you might investigate:

1. .NET Windows Forms - The .NET environment is incredibly powerful and provides for very rapid development. IMO, as rapid as Access if you know what you are doing and far more powerful. However, with those additional capabilities comes additional complexity. No question that jumping into Windows Forms from pure Access development will be daunting but rewarding.
2. Another solution, which I admit to not having tested myself, but looks promising is [Kexi](http://kexi-project.org/) + SQLite which is geared as an open source replacement for Access.

If you considered changing gears and switching to a browser based approach, there are again many choices. PHP, ASP.NET (MVC and not), Ruby and so on. As with Windows Forms, switching to browser based development from Access development will be a daunting change but also rewarding.

Comment: Well, I don't mind manually migrating the queries. It won't be a problem. I'm simply looking for a good way to write a query interface for SQLite (or MS SQL Server Compact or any other portable DBMS). With Access, it was all done in VBA.

Comment: @Matt Basterson - Do you mean a development environment such as ASP.NET or .NET Windows Forms or Java? My recommendation would be .NET but I admit to having a bias.

Comment: I'd prefer to not have to install any additional libraries. I'd like for this to work natively on a lot of Windows machines.

Comment: @Matt Basterson - One way or another, you'll need a runtime. .NET is installed as part of the windows updates and thus can be relied upon to exist and thus would be close to the definition of "run natively" especially with new OS's which have it installed by default.

Comment: Is .NET installed by default on Windows 7 machines? If so, then that's a viable option. Thanks.

Comment: @Matt Basterson - Yes. At least .NET 2.0 is installed by default and later versions might be installed as part of the recommended updates. Even so, it shouldn't be a stretch to have administrators install the framework you wish to use whether it be .NET or Java. .NET can be installed via Windows Updates and Java has its own update engine.

Comment: Great! Looks like its time to brush-up on .NET. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. -1

Comment: @David-W-Fenton - How do you figure? The question is asking for an alternative to Access that does not require an install. SQL Compact Edition is an alternative. That the OP was seeking something not really stated in the question is orthogonal to whether I answered the question given.

Comment: What part of "front end" do you not seem to understand? SQL CE has no front-end development tools. To answer the question you need to offer an alternative database engine AND a front-end development platform. That's why the answer is inadequate, because it only answers the lesser half of the question.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton - Where up to the edits, do you see the words "front end"? Up to the edits, the question has absolutely nothing that implies the UI. I stand by my comment. The nature of the question changed dramatically with the edits.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is a great option and will extend your reach to many platforms beyond Windows (iOS, OSX, Android, etc.).  I recommend this.  If you want to keep using Microsoft products, SQL Server Express or Compact Edition is another possibility.

Comment: That's good. SQLite is looking like a good choice. What is a good way to write a query interface for a SQLite database. Web-based using PHP? Native Windows using C#, VB?

Comment: Almost any method you want will be good.  You can even get a basic query interface as a Firefox plugin (which is what I usually use).  Depends on what you are trying to accomplish and who your users are.  Will they be writing SQL statements?  (You can even do the queries from inside Access using ODBC)

Comment: The users will not be writing queries. I suppose by "query interface", I meant a simple frontend to search the DB.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. -1

Answer (score 1):

Of course, if the PHB are eliminating Access as a cost cutting move, you could split the existing Access databases to Front-end/backend applications, migrate the backends to SQL Server Express edition (free) and have the users use the MS Access run-time (also free)  You, the developer, are the only one who actually needs a paid-for full version of Access.

This response comes long after the question was posted--but Google still turns it up near the top of results for 'replace ms access'

Answer (score 0):

You should include MySQL and PostgreSQL on your list of the potential replacements. MySQL supports AUTO_INCREMENT columns, so it might be a better replacement for the Microsoft databases. Also, Microsoft SQL Server Express might be not a bad option. I migrated from using MS Access databases to using MS SQL Server Express in my apps when I was using Microsoft technologies about 10-12 years ago.

Comment: The problem is your suggestion does not address the forms and user interface part that was also asked of this question. So, what will be used for the UI part of this question? Neither of the tools you mention has forms, reports and a UI for the users. When the poster says a interface to the database, they talking about some kind of UI such as reports, forms, code etc.

Comment: @Albert D. Kallal: I'm not that familiar with the current state of the Microsoft Access development, but at the time I was, it was relatively easy to migrate from MS Access to Visual Basic 6. I hope it is still the case for Visual Basic .NET. If it is not, I'm afraid the migration process would be to drop existing application and to start over, looking at the old app for business rules and UI clues.

Comment: This does not answer the question. -1. As to VB6, "relatively easy" is a pretty unclear statement. Secondly, the reasons the PHBs are eliminating Access would very likely preclude VB6 (which is actually a subset of VBA).

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: Do you have any constructive suggestions for OP? If preserving MS Access code is not a concern for OP, I don't see why MySQL or PostgreSQL or MS SQL Express wouldn't deserve being put on the list of potential replacement for further consideration?

Comment: Answers that offer a replacement for the datebase engine only are not answers to the question asked, which is about the whole package, database engine AND DEVELOPMENT PLATFORM. That's why I applied the downvote, because it's this same old knee-jerk reaction of people who DON'T HAVE A CLUE ABOUT ACCESS who simply propose a completely inadequate answer because it's apparently all they know about,